# How to make shop items link directly to checkout and adding it on the cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been dealing with this for days now and I can't find an answer to this problem. I've been asked to make a woocommerce page in order to buy a specific pack. The idea is that once you choose one of the "packages" go directly to the checkout and adding it to the cart.

This is what I managed to do:

```
// Remove Title single linking

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );

//Image adding to cart and linking to checkout

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_image_add_direct_checkout_link_open', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_image_add_direct_checkout_link_close', 10);

function woocommerce_image_add_direct_checkout_link_open(){
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    $shop_url = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
    $product_id = $product->get_ID();
    if( $product ) {
        echo '<a href="' . $checkout_url . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProductImage-link">
        <a rel="nofollow" href="' . $shop_url . '?add-to-cart=' . $product_id . '">';
    }
}

function woocommerce_image_add_direct_checkout_link_close(){
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
    if( $product )
        echo '</a>
        </a>';
}
```

The problem that I had is that when I try to print two "" one of them is closed automatically and instead of getting one link after another I get 2 links, making only one to work (it can be the checkout or the add-to-cart, and it will depend on which one I put first).

The current html printed on the web is this one:

```
<li>
    <a href="xxx/checkout">
    </a>
    <a rel="nofollow" href="xxx/shop/?add-to-cart=#ID>
        //Code
    </a>
    //add to cart button
</li>
```

And what I like to print will be something like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="xxx/checkout">
        <a rel="nofollow" href="xxx/shop/?add-to-cart=#ID>
            //Code
        </a>
        //add to cart button
    </a>
</li>
```

Any type of help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
This is how it was before the code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="xxx/single_product">
            <img>
            <h2>
        </a>
        //add to cart button
    </li>
    //List of products loop
</ul>
```

Comment: You have 2 functions named the same and do the exact same thing, regardless of that, can we see the page in which you are calling these from? There's not enough to determine what the issue is

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's a copy&paste error I will edit it. And I'm sorry I forgot to comment that this code was made in the functions.php of my child-theme, so the function is called in the Shop page (or Products Archive Page). The actual page is completely void as I tried to make all changes woocommerce-friendly.

Comment: I have edited the text to show how is it printed the HTML without those functions.

Comment: I just did a small test with a tags wrapping inside other tags. `<a href = "test.php?test=1"> test <a href= "test.php?test=2"> test 2</a> end tag </a>` This makes 2 links. "`test`" has the correct link to `test.php?test=1`. `Test 2` also has the correct link going to `test.php?test=2`. However, there is no link on "`end tag`" when we expected `test.php?test=1`. Maybe you need to change your expected results slightly as it will not work.

Comment: The links do work, it is not a link problem, what I'm fighting is that the first tag closes automatically. I may clarify this more in my question, but the problem is that I should have one link inside the other (the second one has "rel=nofollow" attribute that makes this code working, I will add it now to clarify this), but somehow the first link close itself, you can see it in the first comparison.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Looks like it's a problem with the woocommerce itself. I managed to find this topic on it which may be of some help to you. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/8575 Nothing else I can help you with on this project as I am unfamiliar with the framework

Comment: Greatly appreciated the help, although the problem they discuss is pretty old and talk about something else, it gave me an idea on how to address the issue from another perspective, not so woocommerce-friendly but it should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution returning to one of my first codes to solve this. It was impossible, though, to let two  open and it maybe was intended as a security protocol. Then the only thing was to force 2 links into one , I didn't want to use it as javascript so I remembered another hook to redirect 'add-to-cart' links. With that in mind, I found the answer that I needed. The code for making my own loop is this one:

```
//Change product's loop design

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'another_kind_of_loop' );

function another_kind_of_loop(){
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
    $shop_url = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
    $product_id = $product->get_ID();
    $product_sku = $product->get_SKU();
    $img = $product->get_image('fullsize');
    $title = $product->get_title();
    if($product){
        ?>
            <a rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo $shop_url . '?add-to-cart=' . $product_id; ?>" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" data-product_sku="<?php echo $product_sku; ?>" >
                <?php echo $img; ?>
                <h2 class="product-loop_title">
                    <?php echo $title; ?>
                </h2>
            </a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

As you can see I recreated the 'add-to-cart' link with all the information if someday I will be in the need of using other plugins. However, you will need to add this code too:

```
// Redirect 'Add to cart' to 'Checkout'

add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

function redirect_to_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
```

This function will add a redirect to the checkout. And I insist in the word 'add', because it will execute the add-to-cart link anyway, so this will make the trick at least for this problem.